# How do you export org-mode to look like org-indent-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have `org-indent-mode` turned on, so an unordered list like this:

```
* foo
** bar
*** baz
* qux
```

looks like this in my emacs buffer:

```
* foo
  * bar
    * baz
* quz
```

The default `org-latex-export-to-pdf` turns everything into sections/subsections.  But, 
I would like to export to PDF such that the result looks like org-indent-mode, i.e., a simple indented bullet list.  Any one have a solution to this?

Comment: What you show is NOT a list of items, but a hierarchy of titles, subtitles, etc. Write your lists with dashes, instead.